# What functionality does <meta property="fb:pages" content="********" /> provide?

Tags: facebook

I found a webpage with this code:

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="1808554712795420" />
```

What functionality does it provide?

I believe it has something to do with Facebook pages, but after searching and viewing a lot of resources about Facebook pages development, I still can't find clear information.

Comment: Main purpose these days is domain verification, I think. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification/verifying-your-domain#associate-pages

Comment: what is the benefit for domain verification? Thanks

Comment: Main purpose that I know of, is to allow pages to _overwrite_ OG meta data such as title, description and thumbnail, when sharing links from that domain. That is not possible any more under “normal” circumstances, was abused too much and got removed. Pages that have verified a domain as “theirs” however can still change those. It might have additional applications when it comes to advertising.

Comment: @CBroe What do you mean by *overwrite* OG meta data? How can the page owner change it without modifying the HTML code?

Comment: Overwrite the _values_ that get used for the share, dynamically at the time of sharing.

Comment: Set it in the Facebook UI? @CBroe

Comment: When making posts via API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/#custom-image